# AngularJs-Facing issue with ui-number-mask in Portuguese (Brazil) locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

My application locale is Portuguese (Brazil). In Brazil a dot (.) is used to separate thousands and comma(,) is used for decimal. Suppose user enters value 4.878 When user saves the data, it saves the correct value as entered in UI, but when next time page render it shows the round off value(i.e. 5 instead of 4.878). I am facing problem with numeric text box without decimal places,

```
   <input class="inputbox" ng-model="value" ui-number-mask="0" />
```

If I set 2 decimal places for same textbox, then it will show/renders correct value always(i.e. 4.878,00):-

```
<input class="inputbox" ng-model="value" ui-number-mask="2" />
```

Any suggestion, why values are rounding off and how to fix this.

Comment: Can you share some code with us? That'd help

Comment: One more question, what api are u using for this ui-number-mask? I quick google took me to: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks - is it this one?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a localization issue. Have you tried following this? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: Localization is already implemented, if I enter the larger number then its works fine. Suppose i entered 6.666.664, then system shows/render the correct value. Issue occurs only if I enter 4-6 digits value.For 1-3 digits and greater the 6 digits it works fine.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the API ur using (which I still don't know what is it)?

Comment: If there is bug in API, then I should face the same issue in all scenarios, here its works for some scenario. Also I verified my API returns the correct value. Value is rounding off just before rending in UI.